# Firebase functions Realtime Database triggers not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send notification every time a new user signs up, my current code (omitting unneeded code for the question):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const doctorRef = functions.database.instance("myinstance").ref("/doctors/{pushId}");

exports.newDoctorNotification = doctorRef
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const newDoctorID = context.params.pushId;
      console.log("val: " + snapshot.val());
      console.log("key: " + snapshot.key);
      
      const notificationContent = {
        notification: {
          title: "New Doctor",
          body: "A new doctor just signed up! uid: " + newDoctorID,
          icon: "default",
          sound: "default",
        },
      };
      
      snapshot.ref.root.child("device_tokens").child("admin").get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.forEach((adminToken) => {
                console.log("found admin: " + adminToken.val());
                admin.messaging().sendToDevice(adminToken.val(), notificationContent)
                  .then(function(result) {
                    console.log("Notification sent");
                    return null;
                  })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Notification failed ", error);
                    return null;
                  });
                });
            });
      
      return true;
    });
```

and my current database:

[image: database node example]

For some reason when I add a new node, the function is not called at all! But when I try to test it throughout the Google Cloud console function testing, the value comes out as null, the key is "doctors", and the context.params.pushId is "undefined"..

Console output:
[image]

Comment: What new nodes are you adding, new doctors?

Comment: @GrahamD yes, the ones right under "doctors"

Comment: Can you share us with the console testing output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding new doctors then I'm pretty sure that the `doctorRef` should look like this:
`const doctorRef = functions.database.ref("/doctors/{pushId}");`

Then `onCreate` will detect new doctor nodes.

With your current code you are listening for additions to the doctor data attributes.

Comment: I have tried that with no luck